# Implement Abstract Factory Pattern with Dagger 2 in Java

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm trying to understand how to implement abstract factory design pattern with Dagger 2 in java. I know how the abstract factory pattern works but I'm new to Dagger. I tried to look for a good example to understand the same but could not find one. Would really appreciate if anyone could provide a good explanation of how can I implement the abstract factory pattern using Dagger 2!

Comment: Can you please explain what part of Dagger is making this tricky for you? The abstract factory is an excellent technique, and Dagger doesn't do much to complicate it.

Comment: Please show what you have implemented so far.